# Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:12659

Tags: wcf, config

in my config my address details as follows `net.tcp://127.0.0.1:1127/CalculatorService but when the error message is showing Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:12659`

i have simple service with tcp binding and i am running my service from VS2010 IDE with wcf test client and then i am getting this error  **Cannot obtain Metadata from** `http://localhost:12659`

here is my config file details

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All Rights Reserved.-->
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="MyTcpActivation.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">

                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://127.0.0.1:1127/CalculatorService/"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>

                <endpoint address=""
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PortSharingBinding"
                contract="MyTcpActivation.ICalculator"/>

                <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexTcpBinding" 
                contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>

        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="PortSharingBinding" portSharingEnabled="true">
                    <security mode="None"/>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <!--For debugging purposes set the includeExceptionDetailInFaults attribute to true-->
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"/></system.web>

</configuration>
```

please help me to run my service from wcf test client from VS2010 IDE. thanks

Answer (score 4):

This suggests an activation problem on WCF. Metadata are not exposed when there is a problem in your service/config/env.

To get the error message try to open `http://localhost:12659` in your browser and/or check event logs.

As it's a nettcpbinding, the config is a little more complex especially if your are hosting the service under IIS : check that WAS Service is started, Net Tcp Listener Service is Started, net.tcp is in Activated protocols for your web site, configured bindings conftoins ntc.tcp on port 1127 , ...). You may also try a basicHttpBinding first.

For debugging purposes set the includeExceptionDetailInFaults attribute to **true**

```
  <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Comment: i am new in wcf. i have checked Net Tcp Listener Service is started. i have not hosted in IIS or WAS. i just start the service for testing purpose from VS2010 IDE. so when i will run my service from IDE then why then why do i need to start WAS. when i am running my service with httpbinding from IDE then no problem occur. so guide me what to do. tell me that always i need to start WAS when i will not deploy to WAS.

Comment: i mention my port 1127 but in the error message the port number was showing 12659 why? can u tell me why so wired behavior. thanks

Comment: i have not found any service called WAS in my service manager.

Comment: you can not test NetTcpbinding with IIS Express and the default Web Dev Server (IIS Express only supports HTTP and HTTPS). You have to use IIS or a custom service host like WCF Service Host (WcfSvcHost.exe).

Comment: i am using visual studio development server and that is wcf test client try to run the service when i press f5 from IDE.

Comment: can u tell me how to host my service with WcfSvcHost.exe ?

Comment: i am trying to run at the port 8734 for tcp binding. so port can be issue? symantec is loaded at my side. so do i need to give any permission from symantec firewall to the port 8734 ?

Comment: if your service is inside a class lib, it will used WCFSvcHost automatically, but not in a Web Site. Also check how to use it here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552363(v=vs.110).aspx